# Leaflet MarkerCluster bindPopup in loop uses only last value

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I wrote this snippet using the Leaflet MarkerCluster library, and I am trying to programmatically assign different messages to each marker using the bindPopUp method:

```
  var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data['Company Name'])) {
    var temp = {};
    temp['ESG Risk Score'] = 1/data['ESG Risk Score'][key];
    temp['Coordinates'] = [data['Latitude'][key], data['Longitude'][key]];
    temp['Market Cap'] = String(data['Market Cap'][key]).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");;
    temp['Company Name'] = value;
    var message = "<p>ESG score: " + data['ESG Risk Score'][key] + "</p><p>Company Name: " + temp['Company Name'] + "</p><p>Market Capital $: " + temp['Market Cap'];
    markers.addLayer(L.marker(temp["Coordinates"])).bindPopup(message).addTo(myMap);
  }
```

The problem that I am having is that the last `message` gets bound to all the markes on the map.

Is there any way to not have each popup get overwritten by the last value in the loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Due to how you placed your parenthesis, you apply the `bindPopup` method on your `markers` MarkerClusterGroup instead of on your individual Marker:

```js
markers.addLayer(L.marker(temp["Coordinates"])).bindPopup(message)
```

...should have been:

```js
markers.addLayer(L.marker(temp["Coordinates"]).bindPopup(message))
```

Note: you can improve performance by adding all your Markers to the MCG at once only after your loop (use `addLayers`), or by adding your MCG to your map only after your loop.

Comment: Thanks so much! Clearly you know this stuff well.. It worked!